# How to pass a filename parameter to "rake db:structure:load"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm using multiple DBs with Rails 4.2 and have "structure.sql" and "structure2.sql" files.

When I try to load `structure.sql` into `development`, `rake db:structure:load` works fine.
But how can I load `structure2.sql` into `development2`?
Can I pass a filename parameter to `rake db:structure:load`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the filename as an environment variable:

```
DB_STRUCTURE=filename.sql rake db:structure:load
```

or

```
rake db:structure:load DB_STRUCTURE=filename.sql
```

Alternatively you can use this:

```
rails db < filename.sql
```

and it will load the schema on your database.